# Vb.net inheritance classes

Tags: vb.net

Why is there no error in this example and how do i make visual studio warn me to to ban this practice:

Example:
here are two objects:

```
Class Person
 Property name As String
End Class
```

and

```
Class Long_Term_Person
 Inherits Person
 Property address As String
End Class
```

here is the test code:

```
Class TestClass

 Sub test1()
  Dim LTP As New Long_Term_Person
  Get_Address(LTP)
 End Sub

 Sub test2()
  Dim P As New Person
  Get_Address(P)
 End Sub

 Function Get_Address(LTP As Long_Term_Person) As String
  Return LTP.address
 End Function
End Class
```

why does Test2 not fail, when the function requires an Long_term_person with an address property, is there a way to get visual studies to flag this?

Comment: Sure, turn `Option Strict On`. (This is a project-wide setting, too, and you should have it set as a default; it’s under preferences, but I don’t know exactly where.)

Comment: @minitech, make that a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid implicit conversions are usually flagged at compile time. For example, if you replace the P in `Get_Address(P)` with an integer variable, it will generate a compile time error.

This is not the case for inherited classes. Invalid implicit conversions for these will generate a runtime error and not a compile error, UNLESS vb.net is configured to generate a warning or error for all implicit conversions. You can do this for the whole project in Project, Properties, Compile. You can either select Option Strict on, or specify the action for Implicit Conversion specifically.

You can also add `Option Strict On` at the beginning of the source file, so the option only applies to that file.